# How to filter RSS feed results, according to a DOM element in its page content?

Tags: javascript, web-development, client-side, dom, rss

I've a "RSS feed", want to filter its results according to a DOM element in its content!

So, this is the mission I'm looking forward to do:

1. Monitor a "RSS feed" continuously.
2. If new RSS elements were added, get its URLs.
3. Go through every URL's page to check for a specific element.
4. If the checked element's value was "true", return its page URL back as a result, otherwise ignore it.
5. Then finally: Print the returned URLs into a new created "RSS feed", to be used in a RSS-reader.

**My questions are:**

Can that be done only in client-side, or it needs server-side?

What best practices to do it?

Any suggested scenarios?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if this can be done client-side, I am not sure I would recommend it. I suppose you know the website if you are looking for something in particular in its pages, it is not a per user choice, so you would probably be better monitoring the RSS server-side and store the results in a DB from which you could return them to users once they need it. The only reason I can think of to make it client-side is: the user chose to monitor this feed, let them pay the load because the server can't. Most RSS readers (e.g. Feedly) use a DB behind the scene rather than just parsing a feed.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done client-side, but it wouldn't be a "continuous monitoring" scenario, since client-side code only executes when your user is actually viewing your page. Instead it would be a comparison operation between a local cached version of the RSS feed and the latest RSS feed.

Also, this would only be possible if the user views a page on your site. It can't be done if the user is using any normal RSS client to access the feed. This of course because RSS clients read RSS feeds - they do not parse client-side Javascript.

So while it's (kinda) doable clientside, it's definitely much better doing this server side.

You could create a service which polls the RSS feed every x minutes and performs all the necessary operations you specified: Getting the URLs, retrieving the pages from the URLs, and traversing the DOM of each page, for whatever element you are looking for.

The service then updates a RSS feed file on the same server as the service. The URL to this RSS feed can then be distributed to your users.

As for technology, it can be done in most server side languages. If you are comfortable with JS, look into Node.JS. If you are comfortable with .NET, you could create it as a C# windows service, etc.